# Does time have an origin?

Tags: metaphysics, time, universe

First I want to assume that time exists most probably in present and nowhere else. Time is more a concept to evaluate how fast things go if you think about it...

Then I want to consider that if the "time" was created with the Big Bang, it implies that
time didn't exist before Big Bang => no bouncing cosmology which is a pretty big assumption in my opinion.

Also I consider this: A serious hypothesis in my opinion is that before the Big Bang, time didn't exist in the way that everything was in quantum state and in this state, what made the Big Bang is a combination that happened instantly. Maybe something like after an amount of quantum energy is being accumulated in real void (no dimension or a different version with only two, who knows...). Black holes might contribute to this renewing and also absolute zero leads to quantum state that will fatally happen. No more matter => no more dimensions (or just two like the example earlier) => everything compressed in a quantum state => Big Bang.

So all in all, the only rational thinking that something can happen is that it already happened before. The world being then determined (being the most logical explanation, sorry free will...), the matter finishing by being in a quantum state again and another version of our universe emerge again. There are then necessarily a finite amount of number of version, and then a finite amount of time between each loops.

To finish I like to see it like this:

Consider Pi, an universe number, meaning that a finite chain of integers even the biggest you can imagine is not just once in Pi but an infinite amount of time. Now take a "screenshot" of our universe and convert it to decimal (an impossible job of course). This extremely long chain of integers will not just be just once in Pi but an infinite amount of time. The lesson of this? In infinity, what can happen happens again.

Comment: Sorry, this is word salad.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) and read a bit in our [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). The text of this post does make a lot of statements but there is no question proper, nor is it obvious what any of the statements have to do with one another.

Comment: There is no reason to think time has an origin. There is no reason to think time has no origin. Time may have always existed. We do not have the tools to thoroughly examine these questions.

Comment: The word "before" mean at an earlier time, so the phrase "time didn't exist before…" doesn't really mean anything, because you need time for "before" to mean anything. Also, the last paragraph seems to reference that conjecture that π is a normal number, which has not been proven, not that anything in that paragraph is relevant to the rest of the question.

Comment: @Sandejo Look: if you say there is no before, you're in the slop to say there was no causality either. That didn't came from nothing. 
The other option you have is somehow some state infinitely in "no time" which means absolutely nothing. What is your rational explanation? God?

Comment: I'm serious guys, I'm looking for rational explanations here, and I didn't found the shadow of a single one except this one... So please tell me. What is it?

Comment: Causality is a property of the structure of spacetime, so without time, of course, there is no causality. I'm still not sure what it would even mean for time to "come from" something.

Comment: " I'm still not sure what it would even mean for time to "come from" something" There you go! You are supporting a theory that says time came from nothing. The universe came from nothing. Somehow it has always existed because nothing existed before by the way.
I am supporting a theory that says time has no origin! You may say that "our" time as our space-time has been made with the Big Bang, I'm fine with that. Don't you dare say time didn't exist as a whole before because 1 you don't know and 2 you would have to come with a rational explanation other than God/Matrix.

Comment: And this is why nowadays science failed to convince me... The fact that you lack of actual possible rational explanation should hint a good way to convince you that a single rational possibility should be the answer but no.... let's say it can be something else, without even giving a good clue of what it can be. Until then I'm believing my theory...

Comment: When you use words like "before" or "always," you are assuming that you are working within a context in which time exists—otherwise those words would be undefined. The phrase "before time existed" makes as much sense as "above where position exists."

Answer (score 2):

The concept of time only makes sense in a system where change exists. That is literally how we get aware of the passing of time and how we define it. Like we look at a periodic process, classic examples would be the revolution of celestial bodies like sun or moon or your internal time keepers, breathing, heart rate or any other bodily function that goes through a cyclic progression of change and compare that to another progression. So that in the end we could say it took 30 revolutions of the second marker for this action to complete.

This idea that time is what the clock reads, leads to interesting physical consequences because the progression of time is thus relative to your velocity with respect to the clock. So if you go away from the clock you see the progression of time slower if you go towards it it becomes faster. While an observer at rest might look at the same clock and not see any change in the progression of time.

Also if nothing ever changes then the concept of time makes no sense and you might as well say that it doesn't exist. Because if you have no way of telling that the state of the universe is different now compared to 100 minutes from now, how could you tell that difference and how could you tell how long 100 minutes were?

And for now we don't know what happened before the big bang and have so far no ways of knowing it, so speculations about that are pretty moot. And while you might be able to describe the heat death of the universe, when everything comes to a standstill, as one state that doesn't mean that it will collapse and get back into motion it could just rest in that state forever.

Comment: "The concept of time only makes sense in a system where change exist" "Also if nothing ever changes then the concept of time makes no sense"

I never said the universe is in a static state. I say the loop is, but it still needs the present moment to exist.
"And for now we don't know what happened before the big bang and have so far no ways of knowing it, so speculations about that are pretty moot. " 
By definition if time didn't exist before the matter then everything that happened before was in a quantum state. It means the Big Bang happened instantly.

Comment: By simple logic and with the help of thermodynamic laws and E=mc², I can definitely argue that matter didn't come from nothing but from energy. I can also argue that there were no space either because it's in the premise of the Big Bang. Space-time was created with matter.
"And while you might be able to describe the heat death of the universe, when everything comes to a standstill, as one state that doesn't mean that it will collapse and get back into motion it could just rest in that state forever."
No. In the zero absolute no more matter can exist nor dimensions. Does this rings a bell?

Comment: The problem is that simple logic doesn't apply here. Like these laws are meant to describe the general state of the universe as we can see it NOW and allow for interpolations and extrapolations but you're trying to look at the most edgy case of edge cases. Like beyond experimental limits, there are theoretical limits to these laws of physics. Like these laws don't apply beyond a Plank Length/Time and conversely we don't know which other laws apply up until then. Yet that is likely where things got interesting so for all that we know the Big Bang happened in an "instance"... or not.